# Merge two lists in C#

Tags: c#, list, merge

I want to merge two lists with different attributes into one list, but while merging it, I want to check if there is, in this particular example, exact date that is in the both lists, and if there is, I want to take both attributes from that elements, and merge them into one element in another list

**List 1:**

```
List<object> r1 = (from x in sp1 select new 
                   { 
                     x.Imported, 
                     x.Period 
                   }).ToList<object>();
```

*L1 result:*

[image]

**List 2:**

```
List<object> r2 = (from x in sp2 select new 
                   { 
                     x.Dissolution, 
                     x.Period 
                   }).ToList<object>();
```

*L2 result:*

[image]

---

**Wanted result:**

[image]

For now, this is how i merge r1 and r2:

```
 List<object> r3 = new List<object>(r1.Concat(r2));
```

Comment: Please use strong classes instead of anonymous ones.

Comment: That's irrelevant to the question ;)

Comment: I think that one of the goals of stack here is challenge  :)

Comment: @ToTa: That's why its a comment.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Yes it is, but comment of that type is far away from the main problem, i'm concerned that people are tired of reading that type of comments, maybe we can here criticize why I use `List` instead of `IList` but what's the point, will that solve this particular problem..

Answer (score 3):

You could transform them into same type and use stuff like this

```cs
r1
.Select(x => new { Imported = x.Imported, Dissolution = null, Period = x.Period)
.Concat(
    r2.Select(x => new { Imported = null, Dissolution = x.Dissolution, Period = x.Period))
.GroupBy(x => x.Period)
.Select(x => new { Imported = x.Max(e => e.Imported),
                   Dissolution = x.Max(e => e.Dissolution),
                   Period = x.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dictionary

```
Dictionary MyDict<String, List<Object>>;

MyDict[object.Perdiod].Add(object);
```

For each date there will  be an entry in the dictionnary, and it will at this "date index" keep a list of all object that happens at that period.

Easiest way IMO and it does not need to make a O(n) check for every entry added

Just make sure when you add data that it is not null IE

```
MyDict[Object.Period] != null
```

Plus, has Nikhil Agrawal said I would not use Object to keep a list of thing... it feels wrong and is error prone. you might want to declare an abstract class that will be used like an Interface or simply an interface for those items (object).

Answer (score 0):

AFAK you need reflection to achieve this as the name for Anonymous type is assigned at Compile time here an example on how you can achieve what you want

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;   
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<ImportedType> sp1 = new List<ImportedType>();
            List<DissolutionType> sp2 = new List<DissolutionType>();
            sp1.AddRange( new ImportedType[]{new ImportedType() { Imported = 2, Period = "2024-02" }, new ImportedType() { Imported = 2, Period = "2014-11" }, new ImportedType() { Imported = 2, Period = "2024-12" }});
            sp2.AddRange(new DissolutionType[] { new DissolutionType() { Dissolution = 2, Period = "2024-02" }, new DissolutionType() { Dissolution = 2, Period = "2034-02" }, new DissolutionType() { Dissolution = 2, Period = "2024-12" } });    
            var  r1 = (from x in sp1
                               select new
                               {
                                   x.Imported,
                                   x.Period
                               }).ToList<object>();
            var r2 = (from x in sp2
                               select new
                               {
                                   x.Dissolution,
                                   x.Period
                               }).ToList<object>();                
            var r3 = r1.Concat(r2).Except(r1.Where(res =>
                {    
                    object vp2 = r2.SingleOrDefault(res2 => GetValue(res2) == GetValue(res));
                    if (vp2!=null)
                    {
                        return true; 
                    }    
                    return false;
                }));        
        }

        private static object GetValue(object res)
        {
            Type t = res.GetType();
            PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty("Period");
            object v = p.GetValue(res, null);
            return v; 
        }
    }
}
```

//here I  suppose that you implements 2 classes like this

```
public class ImportedType
    {
        public int Imported { get; set;  }
        public string Period { get; set; }

    }
    public class DissolutionType
    {
        public int Dissolution { get; set; }
        public string  Period { get; set; }

    }
```

**Result** 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nikhil Agrawal in that the code now really needs some fixing up, as it is really hard to work with anonymous types, especially since they have been cast to object.

Ignoring that, and accepting it as a challenge (use anonymous types cast to object), this is what I have come up with:

Code that merges does a full outer join:

```
        Func<object, object> getPeriodKey = first =>
        {
            var periodProperty = first.GetType().GetProperty("Period");
            return periodProperty.GetValue(first);
        };

        var temp = r1.GroupJoin(r2, getPeriodKey, getPeriodKey, (obj, tInner) =>
        {
            dynamic right = tInner.FirstOrDefault();

            if (right == null)
                return (object)(new
                {
                    Period = ((dynamic)obj).Period,
                    Imported = ((dynamic)obj).Imported,
                });
            else
                return (object)(new
                {
                    Period = ((dynamic)obj).Period,
                    Imported = ((dynamic)obj).Imported,
                    Dissolution = (int?)right.Dissolution,
                });

        });

        var merged = temp.Union(r2, new RComparer());
```

and the required comparer is below:

```
    class RComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
    {
        public bool Equals(object x, object y)
        {
            var xPeriodProperty = x.GetType().GetProperty("Period");
            var yPeriodProperty = y.GetType().GetProperty("Period");

            if (xPeriodProperty != null && yPeriodProperty != null)
            {
                var xPeriod = (string)xPeriodProperty.GetValue(x);
                var yPeriod = (string)yPeriodProperty.GetValue(y);
                return xPeriod == yPeriod;
            }
            else
                return base.Equals(y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(object obj)
        {
            var periodProperty = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Period");

            if (periodProperty != null)
                //This will essentially hash the string value of the Period
                return periodProperty.GetValue(obj).GetHashCode();
            else
                return obj.GetHashCode();
            ;
        }
    }
```